# cannot be referenced from a static context- switch statement

Tags: java, android

What is this error and how do I fix this? This is driving me nuts.

```
public static void NSOMUHDialog(final Context context) {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
  builder.setTitle("Menu");
  builder.setCancelable(true);
  builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Announcements", "Rate us", "Get support", "How to use?", "Share download link"},
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              switch (which) {
                case 0:
                  if (NSOMUHUpdateChecker.getInstance(context).isOnline()) {
                     // internet is available, fetch announcements
                     new NSOMUHFetchAnnouncements().execute();
                  } else {
                     // device is offline
                     Toast.makeText(context, "not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  break;
```

ERROR:

> NSOMUHMenu.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Post the code where you get the error. As the error message says, you cannot use `this` inside static method because it is not static.

Comment: I know what you mean, bhandari saab, but that's literally where I am getting the error. I just hit ctrl + F and looked "menu.this" up, it is not even there in my entire class, I don't know how It is showing that up.

Comment: My class's name is NSOMUHMenu

Comment: OK Rebuild the project and try again.

Comment: nope, no luck..

Comment: Probably the problem is the code that calls the `NSOMUHDialog(final Context context)` method.

Comment: And be aware that alert dialog can only be called from an Activity.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך nope, that's not true, I have used alertdialogs with services, you need the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, however

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and the info. I never use it with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW before.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call something that does not exist. Since you have not created an object, the non-static method does not exist yet. A static method (by definition) always exists.

Please use **static** keyword in your NSOMUHUpdateChecker class

```
 public static void getInstance(Context context)
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the static keyword from the function declaration

Comment: It would arise other errors without static